# Feature Service layer issues

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, wfs, arcgis-10.1, feature-layer

What is the maximum number of records returned by WFS protocol? What is maximum number of records returned by a Feature Layer in ArcGIS Server 10.1? What is maximum number of records the ArcGIS JavaScript 3.1 feature layer can display?

I am facing a peculiar problem in ArcGIS Server 10.1 and ArcGIS JavaScript API 3.1.
In the capability tab, if I set the maximum number of records to more than 13,000 records, then the layer is not displayed. I am using a relational database and joining 5-6 tables to get the desired data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you've reached your browser's memory limits in regards to the data returned by arcgis server 10.1. The maximum number of records returned by WFS and ArcGIS Feature Layer depend on how it was set up by the server (default is 1000 for anything running through ArcGIS Server). You can reconfigure it to send more, but then you run into poor browser performance.

The question is, do you really need to juggle that much data client-side?
**EDIT:**
Here are some links to help with that juggling act.
[High Performance Web Apps](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/06/29/high-performance-web-apps-with-big-datasets-as-feature-layers/)
[Be Successful at Geoprocessing](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/06/15/be-successful-overlaying-large-complex-datasets-in-geoprocessing/)
[Maintaining High Performance](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/0911/maintaining-high-performance-with-big-datasets-and-interactivity.html) (Derek has some great insight into your direct question).
You don't mention the data "type/use" for your data, this article about parcel fabric has some good memory joggers that can be helpful. [Best practices for migrating](http://www.esri.com/news/arcuser/1012/best-practices-when-migrating-to-the-parcel-fabric.html)
Finally a must link to the video section of the recource center. This one with Sterling.
[Best Practices for Designing Effective Map Services](http://video.arcgis.com/watch/642/best-practices-for-designing-effective-map-services)
[Point Clustering](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=4174dcae65bf42e1b776c17da4b279c1) can help also
It seems that this subject just keeps poping up. Here is another blog from today.
Even if you don't use cache it has more usable information.
[Accelerating map caching creation](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/19/accelerating-map-cache-creation/)

Comment: Actually feature class has 92 thousand records.but I need to show around 20-30 thousand data.which might increase over the period.so any suggetion.Thanks.

Comment: but the question is do you need to "show" that many. What I do is use a scale dependent view and let the request for more data be driven by actual view determining what data is returned. Still can be a large request but much smaller than all the data every time a request is made.

Comment: What you could do is create a graphics layer that shows regions, get the count of how many features match the query you pass in, by region, and display that number in the center of each region.  Or you could try point clustering, per this example: http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/help/jssamples_start.htm#jssamples/layers_point_clustering.html

Comment: @BradNesom how did you do the scale dependent request.Could you direct me to some link.Thanks.

Comment: when setting up the service in arcmap. you can set the layer properties to "not show out beyond" a certain scale. You can then create another simplified version of the data (or use geoprocessing) to show when you are zoomed out. when a user selects data (with whatever means you are programming) that zooms in past the simplified version. There are many techniques that are used to accomplish this simple explanation. But the bottom line is the mapmaker is responsible for creating a managable view of the data that answers all the questions of the user.